# String replace to method

Tags: ruby

I need to replace a localized string to localized method.

From:

```
"social_1.localized()"
```

To:

```
"social_1".localized()
```

What is the best way to do?

Comment: Where does that string come from? Why does it contain `".localized()"`?

Comment: This string generated from the Xcode localization file, generated via another application

Comment: Obviously that other application is generating invalid code. Have you tried to fix it? (not the result but the code generation itself)

Comment: The case is, I need to generate string ".localized()" method like fashion. Because Xcode needs it.

Comment: Please provide some details and more context. Are you writing a tool in Ruby that is supposed to generate code? Is your Ruby tool the "other application"?

Answer (score 3):

May be this:

```
"social_1.localized()".gsub(".localized()","").localized()
```

or

```
my_string, my_method = "social_1.localized()".split('.')
my_method = my_method.gsub!("()",'').to_sym
my_string.send(my_method)
```

@uri-agassi (see comment) is right. using send this way may be a security risk. especially if it comes from user input (i.e. from the params object). you could think about to whitelist callable methods:

```
if [:upcase, :downcase, :capitalize].include?(my_method)
  my_string.send(my_method)
end
```

Or at least ask the object, that it knowns the method to call:

```
my_string.send(my_method) if my_string.respond_to?(my_method)
```

Comment: I would add a big disclaimer about the dangers of calling `send` on arbitrary input... the second option will work, but should be discouraged.